# Why is this code calling an auto release pool?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autorelease

I am seeing the following log...

"__NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x58264b0 of class UITableViewCellContentView autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking "

It is a huge release pool log, above is just one of the release log that i copied...

I have a CustomCell that adds tiles into itself depending on the business Logic. But the problem is when I call the creation of the cell, i see the above log messages. I don't see anything wrong with my code.. Does any one has any clue about it?

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)inTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    UnSavedNoteListCell *cell;
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [@"Cell_" stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row]];
     cell = (UnSavedNoteListCell *)[inTableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


if (cell == nil) 
{

    NSMutableArray *cellProgressNoteCollection = [self getcellProgressNoteCollectionForLandScape:indexPath];
    cell = [[[UnSavedNoteListCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier cellTiles:cellProgressNoteCollection] autorelease];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

}

//    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", rand()];
//    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
// Configure the cell...

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I do notice is that you're not reusing any of your uitableviewcells, so you're probably taking on a big performance hit.  In your code above, you're creating a new cell identifier for every row.  Try this instead:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)inTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UnSavedNoteListCell  *cell = (UnSavedNoteListCell *)[inTableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        NSMutableArray *cellProgressNoteCollection = [self getcellProgressNoteCollectionForLandScape:indexPath];
        cell = [[[UnSavedNoteListCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier cellTiles:cellProgressNoteCollection] autorelease];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    }

    return cell;
}
```

This way, your tableview can maintain a list of tablecells that are marked for reuse.

Answer (score 0):

A better question is why you don't have an autorelease pool.

Here's some of the calls you make in that code that might require an autorelease pool. (Some of them probably don't, actually.):

- `stringByAppendingString`
- `stringWithFormat`
- `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`
- `autorelease`
- `getcellProgressNoteCollectionForLandScape` (if it's written per conventions)
- `clearColor` (theoretically, but probably not)

UIKit requires an autorelease pool.

You have two potential causes that I see:

1. Your autorelease pool is gone. (Where did it go?)
2. This is being called from a thread other than the main thread.